# SVG vs Other Drawing Efficiency with Thousands of nodes

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm working on a project in which I'm dynamically drawing charts, using SVG, rendered server-side. They're simple, plot-like charts, but they contain 10's of thousands of nodes at minimum, but could contain hundreds of thousands, because only 5 properties are being shown by default, out of 144 available. So much so, that when looking at them on firefox's code inspector, when you hit "Show XXXXX nodes", it breaks firefox, and I'm on an extremely capable computer. It looks like rendering this page (with approx. 25k nodes) takes about 4mb of RAM, and a relatively significant amount of CPU resources - when multiplying that by even a few hundred users, it's pretty significant. This is an ASP.NET based solution.

So, my question is, would I be better off rendering/drawing the SVG with javascript client-side, rather than server-side? Or, using pure JS to draw it client-side? My only concern, is someone on a less than capable machine, requesting far too much data and javascript locking up their browser. Also, I'm trying to avoid api's like "google charts."

Thanks!!

Comment: Draw fewer nodes. You can't possibly make sense of 10's of thousands of items in a single drawing.

Comment: The number of data points is requisite to the value of the page.

Comment: I don't accept that's true because it's impossible to make sense of that amount of data on a single page. At any rate as you've discovered SVG is not a suitable technology for 10,000 DOM nodes so choose some other rendering mechanism or as I suggested cut down the number of points drastically.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to assume each DOM node consumes around 1K of memory so you're 21Mb short in the memory you need.

Comment: They're engine logs. Up to 144 data points, as often as every 100 milliseconds. Even when the resolution is brought down to once a second, 5 minutes of logs is 300/property. You use a dot, a line cobbecting this dot with the last, and a label to show the value upon hover, that is 900 items/property.

Comment: And if the resolution is further decreased, the value of the chart is moot.

Comment: Display an appropriate timeframe and fetch the data dynamically if you want to see a different (zoomed in or out) period.

Comment: Hmm.. I can envision something like that.... Diminished resolution at a wider timeframe, increased resolution in a tighter timeframe. Could even make "stand-in" data for wider time frame to represent averages for a better look. You should see the db for this sucker... Lol

Comment: And i double checked out of curiosity, a page with an svg with 29937 nodes is only 2.61MB according to firefox inspector.